# Angularjs - ng grid what is the group name of the selected row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, group-by, selection, ng-grid

Using ng-grid I've build grid with grouping.
When I select a row I want to know what is the group name he is belong to.

```
 afterSelectionChange: function(row, event) {       
      if (row && row.entity && row.selected) {                       
           // what is the group name?
      }
  }
```

The reason I need this info, is because I've changes the column value 
dynamically after the grid is initialized, so The value written in the group title is different from the value in the row.

I've made a plunker demonstrate my problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aAWVToxvGSudQUHcUgaz?p=preview

Please select one of the rows to see the problem.

P.S.
I can't find it under row.entity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save original name into another property for later use. For example in `updateColumnName` plugin code:

```
angular.forEach(self.scope.renderedRows, function(row) {
    if (row.entity.name) {
        row.entity.origName = row.entity.name;
        row.entity.name = '****';
    }
});
```

Then you can read `origName` property when you need:

```
afterSelectionChange: function(row, event) {
    if (row && row.entity && row.selected) {
        alert('group name: ' + row.entity.origName);
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/pdbN6O7m57rMD0khSN16?p=info

Comment: Silly me :), so simple!
Thanks Much, you are great!